# How to modify the starting point position of arrow in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am connecting Node 1 to Node 2 by an arrow. The arrow is overlapping the label. I want the arrow to start from the label rather than the node itself. Is it possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe,
        paperheight=14in,paperwidth=8.5in,
        margin=2in,heightrounded]{geometry}
 \usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[%auto, thick, 
 node distance = 3.6mm and 9mm, 
C/.style args = {#1/#2}{% Color
top color = #1, bottom color=#2},
C/.default = green!40!white/green!20!white,
 N/.style = {% Node
rectangle, rounded corners=2pt, 
minimum width= 24mm, font = \sffamily, 
align=center, inner xsep=1ex,
drop shadow, minimum height = 5mm}, 
every label/.style = {shape=circle, fill=white, text width=4.5ex, align=center,
       inner sep=1pt, font=\sffamily\scriptsize, drop shadow,
       yshift=0.17cm, xshift=-0.15cm}
                                      ]
\node [N,C,font=\bfseries\sffamily] (SWGDAM)   {SWGDAM Guidelines for Validation \\of
                                            Probabilistic Genotyping Systems};
 \node [N,C,label=right:4.2,
   below=of SWGDAM.south east]     
                                        (42)    {Comparative\\ Study};
\node[N,C,label=right:4.1,below=of 42]      (41)    {Data\\ Generation};
 \node[N,C,label=right:4.2.1,below=of 41]    (421)   {Consistency};
\node[N,C=yellow/yellow,
  label=right:4.2.1.1, below=of 421]   (4211)   {Method\\ Comparison};

\node[N,C=gray!40!white/gray!40!white,font=\bfseries\sffamily,
  label=right:7, below = of SWGDAM]     (intval)    {Internal\\ Validation};
\node[N,C=gray!20!white/white,
  label=right:7.1.1,below = of intval]  (711b)  {Template\\ Concentration};
\node[N,C=gray!20!white/white,
   label=right:7.1.2,below = of 711b]   (712b)  {Node 2};

 \node[N,C=gray!20!white/white,
  label=right:3333,below = of SWGDAM.south west]   (3333)  {Node 1};

 \draw [->,red] (3333.north east) to [out=360,in=180] (712b.west);     

  \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What you like to tell with arrow? That "Node 2" is related to label "3333"? If it is related to "Node 1", than is better to draw line as (for example): `\draw [->,red, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm] (A) to [out=270,in=180] (712b);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can name label like this `label={[name=A]right:3333}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe,
        paperheight=14in,paperwidth=8.5in,
        margin=2in,heightrounded]{geometry}
 \usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[%auto, thick, 
 node distance = 3.6mm and 9mm, 
C/.style args = {#1/#2}{% Color
top color = #1, bottom color=#2},
C/.default = green!40!white/green!20!white,
 N/.style = {% Node
rectangle, rounded corners=2pt, 
minimum width= 24mm, font = \sffamily, 
align=center, inner xsep=1ex,
drop shadow, minimum height = 5mm}, 
every label/.style = {shape=circle, fill=white, text width=4.5ex, align=center,
       inner sep=1pt, font=\sffamily\scriptsize, drop shadow,
       yshift=0.17cm, xshift=-0.15cm}
                                      ]
\node [N,C,font=\bfseries\sffamily] (SWGDAM)   {SWGDAM Guidelines for Validation \\of
                                            Probabilistic Genotyping Systems};
 \node [N,C,label=right:4.2,
   below=of SWGDAM.south east]     
                                        (42)    {Comparative\\ Study};
\node[N,C,label=right:4.1,below=of 42]      (41)    {Data\\ Generation};
 \node[N,C,label=right:4.2.1,below=of 41]    (421)   {Consistency};
\node[N,C=yellow/yellow,
  label=right:4.2.1.1, below=of 421]   (4211)   {Method\\ Comparison};

\node[N,C=gray!40!white/gray!40!white,font=\bfseries\sffamily,
  label=right:7, below = of SWGDAM]     (intval)    {Internal\\ Validation};
\node[N,C=gray!20!white/white,
  label=right:7.1.1,below = of intval]  (711b)  {Template\\ Concentration};
\node[N,C=gray!20!white/white,
   label=right:7.1.2,below = of 711b]   (712b)  {Node 2};

 \node[N,C=gray!20!white/white,
  label={[name=A]right:3333},below = of SWGDAM.south west]   (3333)  {Node 1};

 \draw [->,red] (A.south) to [out=270,in=180] (712b);     

  \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `\draw [->,red] (A.south) to [out=270,in=180] (712b.west); ` you can write as `\draw [->,red] (A) to [out=270,in=180] (712b);  `